# google play store issue with tapjoy sdk

Tags: android, google-play, tapjoy

I am using latest tapjoy jar file and follow all the thing which is mentioned on tap joy site, for reference i am using this http://tech.tapjoy.com/product-overview/integration-publishers/getting-started-guide-for-publishers,
but still getting below warning

> We have determined that your app uses a library or SDK (com.tapjoy)
>   that is in violation of the Developer Program Policy. Please note that
>   beginning Aug 1st, 2014 the Developer Program Policy requires all
>   updates and new apps uploaded to be compliant with the advertising ID
>   provision of the Developer Program Policy. Apps in violation may be
>   subject to permanent removal from the Store. Learn more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the last week, we have been very active with Google discussing this warning and the automated checks they've been running.

Our current understanding is the compliance check they are running did not consider the method of detecting Google Play Services via reflection.

Some of you are mentioning the presence of different persistent IDs being sent in the SDK - and that is also not against Google's policies. To be clear - their terms of service allow for this as long as the IDs are not being used for advertising. They also allow for this if there is no Google Advertising ID available on the device. Unlike Apple, Google does not have 100% share of the Android play stores under their control. Several other app stores exist which will not have a Google Advertising ID. Since we are a global company, we have to account for all use cases in our SDK.

We are confident that our use case is entirely consistent with Google policies. We've also received assurances from Google that no apps will be rejected in the meantime. I will make sure to update this post when we have more information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Please keep us posted here if there are any news.

Comment: Absolutely giggsy. I definitely will.

Comment: Do you know how often automated checks are performed? I've completely removed TapJoy from my application but warring is still there. Should it disappear after new version was published or I have to wait few days?

Comment: @lenrok258 the warning went away for me after some time (max 6 hrs) after removing tapjoy from codebase.. how much time has it been for u? Remember u need to remove the library link from properties..

Comment: @MatHarris hey.. whats the status on this.. `Its been 15 days`..We are losing our market everyday because of this mess.. I am sure you must be losing a lot more, as most of your customers would have already removed tapjoy from their apps.. Not only you are losing existing users you are also losing the trust.. Sorry to say this but if this continues your whole product for android will die soon.. I hope it's resolved soon..

Answer (score 7):

So sorry for the delay. We have confirmed that this warning was triggered specifically by our use of reflection to detect Google Play Services.

Our contacts at Google have assured us that no developers who are seeing the above warning in their Developer Console are in jeopardy of having their apps rejected at this time, and it is possible that your apps will not require any updates at all. "Doing nothing" is actually an appropriate response, as far as we know.

However - If you have received this warning, and you want to see that warning removed - we have recently released a new version of our SDK which does not use reflection. **Integrating this SDK will remove the warning.**

Additionally, the Google compliance team has already tested SDK 10.2 and confirms that the non-reflection implementation passes their automated check and does not raise any flags or exceptions.

Version 10.2 is now live on our website. The download link and upgrade instructions can be found here: http://tech.tapjoy.com/product-overview/sdk-change-log/android-release-notes

One thing to note: With SDK 10.2, all Tapjoy calls must now be made after the Tapjoy connect call and connectSuccess() callback returns.
If you are upgrading from an older version of the SDK, and have any Tapjoy calls before the connectSuccess() callback, you will need to move them in order to successfully integrate SDK 10.2.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to jump in and provide a quick answer.

Tapjoy SDK versions 10.1 and above are in compliance with Google's Advertising ID TOS. We confirmed this with our contacts at Google back in July.

We are now actively working with Google to understand why the SDK is generating a warning for some developers.

Curiously - we've also seen that disabling or enabling persistent identifiers in the SDK will not immediately remove the warning. There appears to be some sort of lag between making a change and seeing the results in the Developer Console.

I expect we will have more answers very soon. I will post updates here as they develop.

Best,

Mat Harris
Sr. Director of Ad Products, Tapjoy

Comment: We are still getting a flag on the Google Developer Console that the Tapjoy SDK as non-compliant.  Could you provide some evidence (email / screenshot) from Google that confirms that Tapjoy SDK versions 10.1 and above are in compliance with Google's Advertising ID TOS.

Comment: See Mat Harris' other answer on this page for an update.

Answer (score 1):

From your warning message get the hint that  there may be any upgrade to the sdk or google play

Google Advertiser ID: As of SDK version 10.1, Tapjoy uses the Google Advertiser ID (AID) to serve ads, which is required to pass submission to the Google Play Store. If you are using an older version of the SDK, you should upgrade to the latest version here. You can also learn more about Google AID.
To ensure Google AID is incorporated into your existing project correctly, follow these upgrade instructions.

http://tech.tapjoy.com/product-overview/sdk-change-log/android-change-log-release-notes

Get this message from this link only http://tech.tapjoy.com/product-overview/integration-publishers/getting-started-guide-for-publishers

may be you need to do the changes in your implementation acc to the instructions.

Comment: We released a fresh game (so no potential "old sdk" users) with the latest TJ sdk and still get the warning. The log says it's using Ad-ID. Funny thing is, it also seems to sometimes send the UDID to TJ ... I'm not sure, if it's supposed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

We're in the same boat it seems.
Triple checked our implementation, but still get the warnings in the Google Play backend.

I think the error's either on Google or Tapjoy side:

- Google parses the APKs and sees Tapjoy >> Tapjoy's bad >> Warning
- Tapjoy hasn't fully updated their SDK, as Google would require. I have seen in the Tapjoy logs, that some requests still contain the device UDID ... and I think that's what's Google not liking. I really do hope, that this isn't the case, and furthermore, that this won't get our apps banned, as Google "threatens" to do ...

So right now, we're not taking any further action.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Updated all my apps to sdk 10.1.1, but Google Play still shows that warning for all of them. Even after i have set flag TapjoyConnectFlag.DISABLE_PERSISTENT_IDS.

Also i have contacted tapjoy support and support guy said that their server shows that my apps still send old 9.1.3 as version number of integrated sdk, though locally i see that TapjoyConstants.TJC_LIBRARY_VERSION_NUMBER shows that it is 10.1.1

I don't know what to do. Wait until all my apps will get banned or remove tapjoy.

Comment: "Good" to hear that DISABLE_PERSISTENT_IDS doesn't help ... that would have been a possible next task and thus a waste of time. Sometimes it just sucks when you have to rely on 3rd parties ...